# Attaching Bootstrap to Spring MVC project by webjar

Tags: java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I am trying to add a Bootstrap framework to my Spring MVC project. I can see my page, but without Bootstrap. Application is running at Tomcat 8 with Spring 4.

In browser console I see an error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8088/webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my code, Spring Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.dummy")
@EnableWebMvc  
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  

@Bean  
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {  
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();  
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");  
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");  
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);  
    return resolver;  
}  

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/*");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
}
```

Included dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And sample index.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:set var="cp" value="${pageContext.request.servletContext.contextPath}" scope="request" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="row">     
        <div class="col-md-4"> 
            <h3> 
                Column1</br>
            </h3>
            <ul>
                <li> Row 1 </li>
                <li> Row 2 </li>
                <li> Row 3 </li>        
            </ul>                                
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-8"> 
            <h3> 
                Column 2</br>
            </h3>    
            <ol>
                <li> Row 1 </li>
                <li> Row 2 </li>
                <li> Row 3 </li>                             
            </ol> 
        </div> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

And here is my directories screenshot: 
[image: Directories]

Comment: You have to specify the path like this: registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations( "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"); and in the jsp: <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen' href='webjars/path-to-bootstrap.min.css'>

Comment: I have already specified them, see my code

Answer (score 1):

Along with

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/*");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

You will also need default servlet handler

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

This are same as `<mvc:resources/>` and `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` from xml based configuration needed to serve static resources.

---

Also try

```
@Override
@Bean
public HandlerMapping resourceHandlerMapping() {
    AbstractHandlerMapping handlerMapping = (AbstractHandlerMapping) super.resourceHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
    return handlerMapping;
}
```

Comment: I added servlet handler, but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you manually copy `bootstrap.min.css` to `/WEB-INF/ressources/css` and use `<link rel='stylesheet' href='resources/css/bootstrap.min.css'>` in your JSP? If this works then the issue should be with the classpath expression you have provided. Also when you hit your page do inspect element and in `net` section see if you are getting 404 and for which of the resources.

Comment: I doesn't work either, I'm getting 404 error on css loading in browser console.

Comment: hmm. Can you override one more method `resourceHandlerMapping()` I have added in my answer above and try.